# How to get the text box to scroll

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jscrollbar

In my code i'm trying to make a scroll bar with the a text box. I got the text box but i can't get it to scroll. I keep looking up new solutions but none of them work. If you know what is wrong can you help me

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tutorial extends JFrame
{
  public static void main(String args)
  {
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JTextField jt = new JTextField("TYPE", 200);
    JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jt); 
    JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");
  }

  public Tutorial()
  {
    setTitle("TextBox");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jt.setSize(300,400);
    jp.add(jt);
    jp.add(jb);

    add(jp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the scrollpane to the frame:

```
//jp.add(jt);
jp.add(myScrollPane);
```

You will also need to maybe sure that the horizontal scrollbar is always visible so that the proper height of the scrollpane can be calculated.

Also, when you post code, make sure you post code that can be compiled. The code you posted makes no sense and there is no way you could even have tested the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SamplePane extends JFrame  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1775096938821736542L;

    public SamplePane() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,500);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JTextField jt = new JTextField("TYPE", 200);
        JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jt); 
        jp.add(myScrollPane);

        setContentPane(myScrollPane);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SamplePane frame = new SamplePane();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Another option is to use `scroller.setModel(textField.getHorizontalVisibility());`

  - The advantage of this method is that the `JScrollBar` thumb scroll while selecting text(or the right arrow key).
  - the disadvantages of this method is that the `JScrollBar` thumb is always show if all text removed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class HorizontalVisibilityTest {
  private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  private static final String TEXT = "javascript:(function(){var l=location,"
                                     + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=0;}());";
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(
      ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
      ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setViewportView(new JTextField(TEXT));
    box.add(new JLabel("JScrollPane + VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER"));
    box.add(scroll);

    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField(TEXT);
    JScrollBar scroller = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
    scroller.setModel(textField.getHorizontalVisibility());

    if (DEBUG) { //I'm not sure if this is a bug...
      EmptyThumbHandler handler = new EmptyThumbHandler(textField, scroller);
      textField.addComponentListener(handler);
      textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(handler);
    }

    box.add(new JLabel("BoundedRangeModel: textField.getHorizontalVisibility()"));
    box.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
    box.add(scroller);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 5, 5, 5));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new HorizontalVisibilityTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

// class EmptyThumbHandler extends ComponentAdapter implements DocumentListener {
//   private final BoundedRangeModel emptyThumbModel = new DefaultBoundedRangeModel(0, 1, 0, 1);
//   private final JTextField textField;
//   private final JScrollBar scroller;
//   public EmptyThumbHandler(JTextField textField, JScrollBar scroller) {
//     super();
//     this.textField = textField;
//     this.scroller = scroller;
//   }
//   private void changeThumbModel() {
//     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//       @Override public void run() {
//         BoundedRangeModel m = textField.getHorizontalVisibility();
//         int i = m.getMaximum() - m.getMinimum() - m.getExtent() - 1; // -1: ?????
//         System.out.println(i);
//         if (i <= 0) {
//           scroller.setModel(emptyThumbModel);
//         } else {
//           scroller.setModel(textField.getHorizontalVisibility());
//         }
//       }
//     });
//   }
//   @Override public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
//     changeThumbModel();
//   }
//   @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
//     changeThumbModel();
//   }
//   @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
//     changeThumbModel();
//   }
//   @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
//     changeThumbModel();
//   }
// }
```